# About std:cout in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, std

Is there an error in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std:cout << "hello" "\n";
}
```

GCC detects no error but `std:cout` does not seem standard.

Comment: So just to clarify, your question is about the `std:cout` with 1 colon, not about the `"hello" "\n"` with no `<<` in between?

Comment: Another good sample how `using namespace std;` could harm your code, and obfuscate trivial errors.

Comment: @MrLister You can do that. It automatically concatenates the strings.

Comment: @NeilKirk I knew that, but some of the answers concentrate on that part of the code and are now being downvoted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Pfff, any language construct, when abused, can obfuscate the code. Operator overloading anyone? If you do want to rant about this program, complain about how the OP is setting things up for using `goto`. I mean, why else introduce a label?

Comment: @MrLister I don't think the OP intentionally used a label here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no error. I could rewrite your code to make it clearer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std:
    cout << "hello" "\n";
}
```

You created a label named `std`. `cout` is used unqualified, which is okay since you have the *using-directive* for `std` above it. And you can concatenate string literals by writing them next to each other as you did. This is perfectly well-formed code that prints "hello" followed by a newline.

Comment: so the previously used `std` identifier can be reused as a label?

Comment: @user2029077 Label names are completely separate from other names. It's not "reused" so much as used independently.

Answer (score 4):

You're defining a label `std` and then you're calling `cout`. This is legal because you have `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1):

The code has an issue.
while trying to instruct the compiler to use the namespace std, we are trying to call the function cout which is defined in the scope of std.

thus the correct use of the scope resolution operator is

```
    'std::cout '
```

and not

```
    std:cout.
```

And others have pointed out
by writing

```
    std:
```

what you do is create a label.